# Sequelize CLI commands not returning anything nor errors when running the migrations

Tags: node.js, postgresql, ubuntu, sequelize.js

I'm trying to deploy my app to an EC2 instance. I'm getting stuck when I have to run my migrations. For some reason `sequelize` is not doing anything nor returning any errors when I run `yarn sequelize db:migrate`. Here's what I get:

```sh
ubuntu@ip-172-31-41-25:~/app/vigna/backend$ yarn sequelize db:migrate
yarn run v1.22.4
$ /home/ubuntu/app/vigna/backend/node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate

Sequelize CLI [Node: 14.5.0, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 5.21.3]

Loaded configuration file "src/config/database.js".
Done in 0.56s.
```

My `.sequelizerc` file looks like this:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  config: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'config', 'database.js'),
  'models-path': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'models'),
  'seeders-path': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'seeders'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'migrations')
};
```

Here's `src/config/database.js`:

```js
require('dotenv/config');

module.exports = {
  dialect: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
  define: {
    timestamp: true,
    underscored: true,
    underscoredAll: true,
  },
};
```

I using Docker to create the Postgres database.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-41-25:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
7a959fcd9f21        postgres            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   30 minutes ago      Up 30 minutes       0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   database
```

I really don't know what I'm missing here.

Thanks for the help and let me know if I can provide any other info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by upgrading pg to version 8.3.0 :)